# A concatenation between a literal symbol and a string variable then return const char*

Tags: c++, string, string-concatenation

I want to concatenate a literal symbol "~" with a string variable.

```
string dbFile = "data.db";
const char *temporaryFileName = ("~" + dbFile).c_str();  // it must be ~data.db
cout << temporaryFileName << endl;
```

No errors, but when printing, nothing comes out, why?

Comment: The expression `("~" + dbFile)` creates a temporary object, which lifetime ends with the end of the full expression and so will have been destructed by the time you try to print it. Perhaps you can elaborate on the *real* problem you try to solve, and we could help you with that instead? Here's some [related reading about the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: I just want to change the current database file name from data.db to ~data.db to pass it to another function.

Comment: Then how about changing the other functions signature to accept a `std::string` argument? Or if you can't modify it (it's not your function, for example) then you could perhaps *overload* it to take a `std::string` argument, and call the real function. Or just store the temporary string in a variable that you can use when calling the function.

Comment: Or, you know, use the expression `("~" + dbFile).c_str()` as the *argument* to the function.

Comment: Anyway, I thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the return type of the operator that you use:

```
string operator+(const char* lhs, string& rhs); // untempletized for simplicity
```

Note in particular that it returns a new object. As such, the expression `("~" + dbFile)` returns a new temporary object. Temporary objects exist only until the full expression statement (unless bound by a reference). In this case, the statement ends at the semicolon on that same line.

Using the pointer returned by `c_str()` is allowed only as long as the pointed `string` object still exists. You use the pointer on the next line where the string no longer exists. The behaviour is undefined.

A solution: Either modify the original string, or create a new string object. Make sure that the string object exists at least as long as the character pointer is used. Example:

```
string dbFile = "data.db";
auto temporaryFileName = "~" + dbFile;
cout << temporaryFileName.c_str() << endl;
```